# Does the triangle in this image consist of four triangles or do four triangles constitute one triangle?

Tags: word-choice

[image: a triangle divided into 4 triangles]

Some people might say there are five triangles, but linguistically should I say there is one triangle which consists of four triangles, or there are four triangles which constitute one triangle?

Is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: Lingustically, it makes sense to say that there are 5 triangles, because there are. Whether one triangle contains other triangles doesn't matter.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Then, should I say it’s logically wrong?

Comment: I can't answer that because I'm not sure how narrowly you mean the term "logic". Besides this is not the SE for that.

Comment: @FeliniusRex But “and” means ‘plus.’ A triangle plus a triangle plus a triangle…?

Comment: "And" and "plus" do not always mean the same.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question really is.  Are you just asking how we should describe this shape?

Comment: @Michael Harvey I’m really sad. I sometimes think dictionaries are useless. There’s no universal truth.

Comment: @stangdon No, I’m depressed.

Comment: I'm not really sure this is a question that ELL can answer. I'm voting to close.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Why are dictionaries not exact. For example, to see is to perceive something with eyes according to dictionaries but if dust is in my eyes and it hurts me why not seeing the dust?

Comment: OP, that is not a question for ELL. That is a question for a different SE. Dictionaries are inexact in EVERY language.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Human beings are so imperfect. Please console me… I’m really discouraged…

Comment: There are multiple equally valid ways of describing this shape, and the differences among them are unrelated to learning English. This is an opinion-based philosophical question rather than one about learning English, so I'm closing it to new answers.

Answer (score 2):

> - There **is** one triangle which consists of four triangles.
> - There are four triangles which constitute one triangle.

are both grammatically valid, and each describes the figure reasonably well. There is often more than one accurate way to describe an image, or an event.

If it makes sense to argue which is the **correct** description, that is, in my opinion, off-topic for this site.

In standard English, one does not say or write:

> there **are** one triangle

because of number agreement. "One triangle" is singular, and so a singular verb form is required.